# Is this a correct way to check if an argument value is part of a defined range of values?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am using the following "assert" to validate the argument value in a function
I have a function "test" that takes a boolean input "arg1" that can be None, True or False. Is this ok to make sure "arg1" is only one of those possible values?

```
   def test(arg1=None):
       assert arg1 in set([None, True, False]), "Not a valid input"
...
```

My friend tells me the following:

> Can't do this. You have to compare True, False, and None as identities (is not =). Doing an in is equivalent to multiple ='s. You have to maintain separate is's.

Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that's true. `1 in {True, False, None}` returns `True`. `any(1 is o for o in {True, False, None})` returns `False`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your friend is correct in the case of `None`; you should always use identity to test for it unless you're okay with just "noneness" (which you almost never are).

As for `True` or `False`, you need to examine whether you need the exact values or if just the truthiness is required. If the former then you can use `in` to test for them, but if the latter then you shouldn't test at all and just pass the argument to `bool()` when you use it in a boolean context.

But there is another problem in your code that both of you have missed:

*Assertions should not be used for decision making.*

Assertions should be used when actions would have a deleterious effect on the system, not for just validating input.

Comment: Do you suggest the use of contracts for that purpose?

Answer (score 4):

If you need identity testing, you must use "is."  Your friend is correct, as "in" uses equality testing.  For example:

```
a = [0, 1]
False in a
>> True
a[0] is False
>> False
```

If someone passes in a 0, it will not trigger your assertion.  You may not be expecting that.